# Check the minimum Android(Sdk) version of react-native npm package

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, sdk

I want to check the minimum android(SDK) version of `react-native` npm packages. I want to check version of [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-bootsplash) package and [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-call-log) package.

I searched on google for How to do that but there are no relevant results for the same. I also checked on packages documentation but didn't get anything there also.

It may be a silly question for you but not for me as I am very new to react-native.

Can anyone please help me with the same?

Comment: https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-bootsplash/blob/master/android/build.gradle

Comment: https://github.com/wscodelabs/react-native-call-log/blob/master/android/build.gradle

Comment: It means react-native-bootsplash minimum sdk version is 16?

Comment: As you can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may do this by the following steps:

1 - open Repository link from npm site

2 - explore folders and open android/build.gradle

3 - search for minSdkVersion

for example react-native-bootsplash will define [here](https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-bootsplash/blob/master/android/build.gradle#L26)

Comment: Okay, Thanks for answering brother

Comment: Can you please tell also that How I know that 16 version belongs to which Android version?

Like 19 sdk version belongs to android kitkat. I want that chart where I will get that info

Comment: find it here https://source.android.com/setup/start/build-numbers

Comment: API level means sdk version?

Comment: One more help, please. I want to change the minimum SDK version in build.gradle. But in the minSdkVersion property, they have used "rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion". Where can I find that file in which they have specified minSdkVersion?

Comment: You can find this definition in build.gradle under android folder android/build.gradle not android/app/build.gradle

Comment: Yeah, I got it.

Comment: It isn't always as easy. Sometimes it is defined by some variables in other file